# Android Geolocation working in emulator but not working in phone

Tags: java, android, gps, android-permissions, android-gps

I made a simple app with geolocation that displays current location of the user in text views, like latitude, longitude and with **Geocoder** cityname countryname postal-code, etc.

Everything works perfectly in the emulator but for some reason the location doesn't get retrieved in my mobile.

The emulator is running android 7.1 and my mobile is running android 7.0 but that should not be a problem because I made the app with 6.0 marshmallow in mind.

***Here is the code***

**"Mainactivity"**

```
package com.example.slimshady.LocationInfoApp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    TextView latitude, longitude, city, postcode, country;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        latitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        city = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.city);
        postcode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.postcode);
        country = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.country);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                updateLocationInfo(location);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

        // asking permission starts here
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){

            // api level lower than 23 so no need to ask for permission

            try {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListener);

            }
            catch (SecurityException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {

            // api level greater than or equal to 23 checking if has permission if not VVVV this condition
            // means go ask for permission

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
            }
            else{

                // means api level greater than or equal to 23 and already has permission
                // so no need to go out and ask for permission

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListener);

                // last known location because we went to this part means we have been here before
                Location lastKnownLocation =  locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                    updateLocationInfo(lastKnownLocation);
                }



            }

        }
        // asking permission ends here


    }

    public void updateLocationInfo(Location location) {

        geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

        try {

            List<Address> locationAddress = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(),1);
            if (locationAddress != null && locationAddress.size() > 0) {

                latitude.setText("Latitude: "+String.valueOf(locationAddress.get(0).getLatitude()));
                longitude.setText("Longitude: "+String.valueOf(locationAddress.get(0).getLongitude()));
                city.setText("City: "+String.valueOf(locationAddress.get(0).getLocality()));
                postcode.setText("Post Code: "+String.valueOf(locationAddress.get(0).getPostalCode()));
                country.setText("Country: "+String.valueOf(locationAddress.get(0).getCountryName()));

            }


        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            startListening();

        }
    }

    public void startListening(){

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListener);

        }

    }
}
```

The code is simple and basic, everything should work fine but for some reason it doesn't.

**I mean the GPS receiver in my physical device works with google-maps so I know its not broken.**

***See it works in the emulator fine***
[image: Image of it working in the emulator]

But the same code does not work on my mobile and I have added all the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**See the same app doesn't work on my physical device, this is a screenshot from my physical device**

[image: Screenshot of it not working on mobile]

As you see the location is on and I have granted permission when asked in the popup.
And last but not least to show that the GPS receiver works and is not damaged in my physical device.

Screenshot of me using google maps
[image: Screenshot of me using google maps]
***I circled in red the GPS on and that maps can get my GPS location***

Comment: you can try this code to get your current location :- https://github.com/kdblue/GetMyCurrentLocation

Comment: Which version are you trying to use on the device? Debug or release?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using released apk in physical device then you have to add SHA1 for release apk in restriction section of Google API console . I think it helps .

If not, then please show your logcat error by debugging app in physical device.

Comment: No i was using android studio adb to deploy the app

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways that your device can locate itself. These are frequently confused as "GPS" when they are not.

1. **GPS (Global Positioning System)** This is a Global Navigation Satellite System (GNSS) which relies on signals from an orbiting constellation of satellites to locate the device. GPS specifically refers to the constellation of satellites deployed by the United States Department of Defense. Alternatives include GLONASS (Russian) and Galileo (European).
2. **Network** This uses WiFi or Bluetooth signals to locate your device. The device scans for transmitters IDs, then sends those IDs to a server over its internet connection to lookup in a database. The server responds with a location.

Your code currently uses only `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`, which uses only satellites to locate your device. Google Maps may be using Network location, which can still work when GPS is disabled.

I suspect you need to either:

1. Add `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`
   or
2. Enable GPS on your device. This is somewhere under Settings and Location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved issue like yours totally removed location manager, and make all location work based on `FusedLocationProviderClient`, also I was have some strange bug on samsung s8 with `LocationSettingsRequest` that can start default dialog to turn on gps, it was worked with bugs but after removing `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates` it works perfectlly with fused.